# Terminal displaying error before loading zsh shell

Tags: terminal, shell, zsh, ubuntu-20.04

After successfully customizing my terminal with oh my zsh and powerlevel9k, it now taking 3 sec (average) to load and it will display the following error

`/home/b-hantsi/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh:source:125: no such file or directory: /home/b-hantsi/.oh-my-zsh/themes/powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k.zsh-theme`

> b-hantsi is my username

I am using ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: So fix the missing file. It tells you exactly what is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this you need to navigate to that folder and edit the file **oh-my-zsh.sh** file, to do that open your terminal and run the following commands:

```
cd .oh-my-zsh/
```

and then:
`gedit oh-my-zsh.sh`
Navigate to line 125 where the error is if you found something like this **source "$ZSH/themes/$ZSH_THEME.zsh-theme"** comment it out, save and restart your terminal